# With Gtk3, how do I make a tree view accessible?

Tags: accessibility, gnome, gtk3

I'm working on a Python+Gtk3 application with a fancy-looking GtkTreeView:
[image: Screenshot of the application with a tree view]

This is great for sighted users, but here's what Orca (the screen reader) says for a row in that tree view:
"Image, Devhelp, Collapsed, 9.2 MB"

A few problems, of course. First, it doesn't mention the checkbox for each row because I'm packing three cell renderers into a column. The three are available, but for some reason Orca doesn't mention the checkbox when it's buried that deep. Meanwhile, the image it mentions is the one on the far left, which is usually empty but sometimes a "restart required" indicator. Naturally, a blind user, much like a sighted user, couldn't care less that it is an image.

What I would like to do is to poke at the accessibility objects that describe this table in order to make them a little more helpful. Using Accerciser, I can see that these exist, but they all seem to be implemented with private, undocumented classes (like GtkTreeViewAccessible), and they don't look terribly extensible, but I'm hoping I'm wrong. Knowing that the treeview's accessible object is an AtkTable at some level, I did the following to set an accessible description for the image cell in the Backup row:

```
    access = self.treeview_update.get_accessible()
    cell_access = access.ref_at(0,0)
    cell_access.set_image_description("Requires system restart")
```

(Orca still says "Image" after speaking the description, but I'll assume it knows what it's doing).

However, that code isn't very nice. When I call access.ref_at, I'm making particular assumptions about how GTK is mapping cell positions to rows and columns in the ATK object. I'm also limited to calling that when I first populate the tree, and I'm not sure if that is particularly sane.

So there's my problem: I would like to add accessible descriptions for my tree view cells in a nice way that won't break unexpectedly. How can I do that?

Comment: I would suggest to ask in GNOME accessibility mailing list (https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/gnome-accessibility-list) and/or point them out to your question here.